# C++ В одномерном массиве в заданном пользователем диапазоне,найти сумму элементов,значения которых меньше указанного пользователем

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio, for

Задание:

В одномерном массиве, заполненном случайными числами в заданном пользователем диапазоне,найти сумму элементов,значения которых меньше указанного пользователем.

Не могу понять, почему ответы больше чем должны быть[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
    #include <iostream> 
#include <random> 
#include <time.h> 
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int arr[10];
        cout << "Enter limit(less than 10): ";
        int n, sum = 0;
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 15;
        }
        for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        int x, y;
        cout << "x = ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "y = ";
        cin >> y;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i]<x) sum += arr[i];
            if (arr[i] > y) sum += arr[i];
        }

        cout << sum;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: По-моему, вы делаете что-то не то. Условие *массиве, заполненном случайными числами в заданном пользователем диапазоне* подразумевает указание диапазона до генерации чисел. А *сумму элементов, значения которых меньше указанного пользователем* — ввод еще одного значения. Итого - 4 значения, включая размер массива. Вы же делаете случайные значения из предопределенного диапазона от 0 до 14 включительно, а суммируете элементы, не попавшие в некоторый указанный вами диапазон... Вернее, вы хотели бы это сделать, но поскольку вводите `x > y`, то вы некоторые элементы вообще суммируете дважды...

Answer (score 0):

Правильно написал @Harry - Вы просто выбираете не числа из диапазона, `y < number < x`, а числа из 2 отдельных диапазонов `y < number` и `number < x`. Т.о. из вашего примера число 8 просуммируется дважды, т.к. оно больше 7 и меньше 10.
Должно быть примерно так:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            if (arr[i] < x && arr[i] > y) 
                sum += arr[i];
```

Ну и да - решение не соответствует условиям задачи. Вы ищете числа, попадающие в диапазон. А по условиям задачи должны генерировать числа (заполнять массив) из предопределенного диапазона, а потом в массиве искать числа, меньше определенного значения.